# Dice adventure in the river Styx

Tags: code-golf

You're sitting in the school cafeteria, microwaving your food like you always do around lunch. Suddenly the programming devil rises from the ashes of your burnt food and proposes a challenge:

> Sup guys, I have a challenge.

How did this happen? What did you ever do wrong? Was it that one bad macro in C?

The programming devil demands a game of dice:

> I demand a game of dice.

Strictly speaking, it is not a game of dice. The programming devil just wants you to calculate the mean value of throwing a die `n` times. The programming devil's twist is that the die can, and always will, have a number of  faces larger than `n`.

### Challenge:

Write a program which calculates and outputs the mean value of `n` throws with a die with a number of faces greater than `n`.

### Input:

Two positive integers. The first argument determines the number of throws, the second argument the number of faces of the die. There is no empty input - always two integers.

### Output:

The mean value of throwing the dice `n` times rounded to the closest integer.

### Requirements:

- No output if the number of faces of the die is less than or equal to the number of throws.
- The values returned from throwing the die has to be random (*as close as we can get to random, that is*)

The programming devil thinks this is great and will restore the burnt food of the programmer which writes the shortest code in bytes to solve his challenge:

> This is a great challenge. I will restore your food if you propose the shortest program in bytes to me.

Comment: Doorknob's answer brings up a good question:  Are we actually supposed to generate a random number `n` times and the provide the mean, or provide the theoretical mean of rolling the dice?

Comment: You're supposed to generate `n` die throws of a die with a number of faces greater than `n` and calculate the mean value of all throws. Do you think I can clarify this better in the question somehow?

Comment: Rather than no output, can the output be something benign when faces <= throws, like 0 which is impossible in this case?

Comment: You say that "*the die can, and always will, have a number of faces larger than `n`"* but then later "*No output if the number of faces of the die is less than or equal to the number of throws*." Which one is it?

Comment: Does an error message count as "no output"? In TI-BASIC, error messages are displayed on top of the homescreen, so no characters are written to the homescreen.

Comment: Can we write a function which takes two arguments?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Death by Shock Probe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/death-by-shock-probe-thats-a-lot-of-dice) as 1) this challenge requires the mean of the dice rolls, whereas the other challenge requires the sum and 2) this challenge has a variable number of dice, whereas the other challenge has a set number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ostrich 0.7.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/releases/tag/v0.7.0-alpha), <s>18</s> 23 chars

Two solutions, identical in length:

```
:x;.,{;xR*C}%_+*\/o2/+F
\:x{.R*C\}*;]_+*x/o2/+F
```

Edit: +5 characters to each because I forgot to round to the nearest integer.

They both actually simulate rolling the dice (and thus have non-constant output), which seems to be the intent of the challenge.

Explanation of #1:

```
:x;     store the number of faces in x, pop from stack
.,      create range from 0 to [number of rolls] (while keeping #rolls on stack)
{...}%  map over that range...
  ;       discard the number
  xR*     generate a float between 0 and [number of faces]
  C       take ceil, which will make this an int between 1 and [#faces]
_+*     reduce by {+} (_ is the syntax for a single-instruction block) a.k.a. sum
\/      swap top two stack elements (bringing the number of rolls to the top),
          then divide, resulting in the average
```

Explanation of #2:

```
\       bring the number of rolls to the top
:x      store number of rolls in x, but don't pop from the stack
{...}*  that many times...
  .       duplicate the number of faces
  R*C     get the random number as described in #1
  \       stick that under the number of faces again, so [#faces] is still on top
;       discard the extra [#faces]
]_+*    wrap stack in an array, sum
x/      divide by [#rolls]
```

Comment: These don't look like they have empty input if `faces≤throws`.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't Golfscript?

Comment: @BetaDecay Ostrich was designed to be as similar as possible to GolfScript. ;)

Comment: @Doorknob Cool. How much better is it?

Comment: @BetaDecay [Not much](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22556508#22556508). The main reason I made it is because Golfscript annoyingly doesn't have a REPL and is missing a few key operators. (see [another chat link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22280628#22280628)) Of course, CJam, Pyth, & co. are much better; I haven't gotten around to learning those though :P

Comment: @Doorknob Nice. Haven't checked it out, so I hope it has betters docs than Golfscript

Comment: @BetaDecay [sorry...](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/blob/master/doc/builtin.md) :P I should really work on those docs more someday.

Comment: @Doorknob Your definition for `B` is hilarious 

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>16</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

Straightforward. The +8/-1 consensus on meta is that mixing inputs is allowed—so `Ans`, from command-line input, is the number of faces, and `N` is the number of throws.

```
Input N
If N<Ans
int(mean(1.5+int(Ansrand(N
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
{0⍕⍺÷⍨+/?⍵⍴⍺}
```

This creates an unnamed dyadic function where the left argument `⍺` is the number of throws and the right argument `⍵` is the number of die faces. Here we sum (`+/`) `⍺` random numbers between 1 and `⍵` (`?⍵⍴⍺`) and divide that by `⍺` (`⍺÷⍨`). The result is rounded to the nearest integer (`0⍕`).

You can [try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B0%u2355%u237A%F7%u2368+/%3F%u2375%u2374%u237A%7D%20%u22C4%205%20f%2021&run).

Note that this still produces output even when the number of throws is greater than the number of faces. But per the challenge rules, that does not constitute valid input (*"The die can, and always will, have a number of faces larger than `n`."*).

Comment: This doesn't have empty output when `faces≤throws`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 17 bytes

I'm sure it can be shorter, but the checking is stopping me from putting it in a lambda.

```
I>QKvz.RcsmhOQKKZ
```

[Try it here online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=I%3EQKvz.RcsmhOQKKZ&input=5%0A10&debug=0)

### Or if the second interpretation of the rules is correct, 12 bytes.

Same thing but in a lambda.

```
M.RcsmhOHGGZ
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M.RcsmhOHGGZ%0A%0AgvzQ&input=5%0A10&debug=0).